# Terraform for_each issue with data type

Tags: foreach, terraform

i have the next code to attach snapshot policy to existing disks for particular instance:

```
data "alicloud_ecs_disks" "db_disks" {
  instance_id = alicloud_instance.db.id
}

resource "alicloud_ecs_auto_snapshot_policy" "common" {
...
}

resource "alicloud_ecs_auto_snapshot_policy_attachment" "db" {
  for_each                = { for disk in data.alicloud_ecs_disks.db_disks.disks : disk.disk_id => disk }
  auto_snapshot_policy_id = alicloud_ecs_auto_snapshot_policy.common.id
  disk_id                 = each.key
}
```

When i run plan it works well, but after applying the next plan fails with error:

```
data.alicloud_ecs_disks.db_disks.disks is a list of object, known only after apply
│ 
│ The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be
│ determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will
│ be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply
│ only the resources that the for_each depends on.
```

What the best option to workaround this? it works using plan on some machines and sometimes not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that your `alicloud_ecs_disks.db_disks` references `alicloud_instance.db` which is probably created in the **same configuration**. As the error msg says, you can't use dynamic data in `for_each`.

The solution is to use [-target option](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting?in=terraform%2Fcli) first to deploy your `alicloud_instance.db` first, and then when it has been deployed you can proceed with the rest of your infrastructure.

If you don't want to split your deployment, then you have to **re-architect** your TF so that there is no dependency on any dynamic content.

Comment: Instances already is deployed and have IDs in a state file. Is any idea how it could be re-factored ? locals can help here somehow?

Comment: @BigBoss How come its deployed? Your TF won't even run with your errors.

Comment: Firstly I deployed instances, after that i'm trying to add this new resources with data, policy and attachment

Comment: @BigBoss if you did it with target option, I don't see any reason why it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during first apply snapshot policy has been attached to the system disk. It forces the whole instance re-creation on next plan and instance.id is not know until apply.